# Eclipse not exporting external jar libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, export, exe, executable-jar

I'm trying to make this .exe file of my eclipse project for my teacher, but every time I do it gives me errors claiming that the lwjgl libraries aren't in there. However when I exported the runnable jar from eclipse that I used to make the .exe from, I selected "Package required libraries into generated jar." I tried running the .jar through the command prompt, but it gave me these errors (click the link): https://scontent-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/11059766_1609765759310316_8110952137507721084_n.jpg?oh=af235bc0bdb7ecf1e4d875619bd20631&oe=55D1E928

I don't know why it's doing this. I need this executable by tomorrow and it's already like 10:47 PM and I'm freaking out! Could someone PLEASE help me?!?!

EDIT

I tried selecting "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" instead, but gave me "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path"

Comment: Have you added all the libraries to the build path?

Comment: We need to see how you built the Mega Man JAR (great video game, by the way).

Comment: Type: `jar -tvf "Mega Man Java Engine.jar"` from the command prompt.  It will show you what is inside that JAR.

Comment: AFAIK, "Package required libraries into generated jar" doesn't work for native libraries (which can't be packaged into the generated jar).

Comment: @immibis I tried "extract required libraries into generated jar" and it didn't work either. It just gave me an unsatisfied link error.

Comment: @Entity1037 I know. Eclipse has no option to make it work automatically.

Comment: Did you try just copying lwjgl's dll files into the same folder as the JAR?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem! I changed the lwjgl libraries from being an external library to it being in a folder inside the project, and then I exported it with the required libraries outputed to a folder next to the jar, and then created a fat jar using JarSplicer. Now, however, I'm having this other issue that makes it unable to get image and sound resources even though (I checked with 7-zip) they are in the correct file position. I'll post another question for this other problem.